# confused with the arguments of a method?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a class with the following structure:

```
class Detection
{
    public:
        void processImage (cv::Mat& image);
        void setGobalPositionCalculator (Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float horizontalAngle, float verticalAngle));

    private:
        Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float, float);

};
```

Then the methods are declared as following:

```
void Detection::setGobalPositionCalculator (Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float, float))
{
    this->globalPositionCalculator = globalPositionCalculator;
}

void Detection::processImage(Mat& image)
{
        if (globalPositionCalculator)
        {
            landmark.position = globalPositionCalculator (hAngle, vAngle);
        }
}
```

**Problem 1:**

I am not able to understand the "Argument" format of `setGobalPositionCalculator()`. I have always seen that arguments are separated by `comma( , )`

**Problem 2:**

`globalPositionCalculator` is not a member varibale of the class then how can `processImage()` get a access on it ?

Comment: it *is* a member variable: this->globalPositionCalculator = globalPositionCalculator;

Comment: @berak: In `processImage()` in the line ` landmark.position = globalPositionCalculator (hAngle, vAngle);` what is `globalPositionCalculator`....is it also a pointer...or a normal method?

Comment: the assignement assings a pointer, but from then on you can use it as a method. (even without dereferencing, if that confused you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 1

The arguments you are seeing is a `function pointer`, all the following is ONE `function pointer`

`Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float horizontalAngle, float verticalAngle)`

It is saying that this pointer, points to a method that has the following:

```
   Point3D methodName(float horizontalAngle, float verticalAngle);
// ^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Return type^       arguments
```

And your `globalPositionCalculator` is the pointer that points to `methodName`

Check this barebones example from [cprogramming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

```
#include <iostream>
void my_int_func(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int);
    foo = &my_int_func;

    /* call my_int_func (note that you do not need to write (*foo)(2) ) */
    foo( 2 );
    /* but if you want to, you may */
    (*foo)( 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

### Problem 2

You **must** call the `processImage` method *after* the `setGobalPositionCalculator`, this is mandatory, otherwise nothing will happen.

Now if you look closer on the `setGobalPositionCalculator`

```
// I changed the function pointer variable name to add clarity to this example
void Detection::setGobalPositionCalculator (Point3D (*thefunctionpointer) (float, float))
{
    // In the next line a member variable of the Detection
    // object is set to the pointer you just passed
    // they are different variables
    this->globalPositionCalculator = thefunctionpointer;
}
```

Now when you get to your next method

```
void Detection::processImage(Mat& image)
{
    // you are checking the private member
    if (this->globalPositionCalculator)
    {
        landmark.position = this->globalPositionCalculator (hAngle, vAngle);
    }
}
```

Of course they removed the `this` pointer because it does *nothing*. But as you see, it adds clarity to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The type of argument to

```
void Detection::setGobalPositionCalculator (Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float, float))
```

is a pointer to a function that expects two `float`s as argument and returns a `Point3D`.

Example usage:

```
Point3D foo(float f1, float f2)
{
   Point3d p;
   // Do the necessary calculations to set the data
   // of p by using f1 and f2

   return p;
}

Detection d;
d.setGlobalPositionCalculator(foo);
```

Comment: The argument type is "pointer to a function". When you call the function, the argument has to match with the type that `Detection::setGlobalPositionCalculator()` expects.

Comment: @user2756695 I edited my answer to elaborate the point a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

`globalPositionCalculator` is pointer to function wich gets two `float` numbers, and return `Point3D`. To understand better you can start reading here [Function_pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

The person who wrote this `class` actually expects that you know how `global Position` will be calculated, so you need to write a function with given prototype, and pass it as argument to `setGobalPositionCalculator` method, later he uses that logic while processing image to calculate the landmark postion.

**Edit: answering you comment**
Code instructions have addresses. Function name is actually address of  first instruction of the function. Somewhere in that class should be definition of function pointer `globalPositionCalculator`. This statement

```
       `this->globalPositionCalculator = globalPositionCalculator;`
```

assigns address of some piece of logic that knows how to calculate global position to eth class memer `globalPositionCalculator` which is pointer to a function. Later in `processImage` method, the program will jump to that piece of code, process it and will take it's return value, and processImage will continue with its flow.

Comment: could you please tell me what this line is doing `this->globalPositionCalculator = globalPositionCalculator;` and how `processImage()` is able to acess `globalPositionCalculator` pointer?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
void Detection::setGobalPositionCalculator (Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float, float))
```

can also be expressed through:

```
//// an "alias" used when this type of function pointer is needed a lot
typedef Point3D (*globalPositionCalculator) (float, float);

void Detection::setGobalPositionCalculato(globalPositionCalculator funct_ptr);
```

The "member" you mean, can be acessed by simply calling the function_ptr:

```
Point3D myFunc(float x, float y); // declaration --> must be implemented

globalPositionCalculator atPos = NULL; // init
atPos = &myFunc; // this is basically what Detection::setGlobal[...] does.

float m_X, m_Y;
atPos(m_X, m_Y);  // call function (e.g. with object params).
```

In Class:

```
 class A {
    public:
        void setter(globalPositionCalculator func_ptr) { m_Ptr = funct_ptr; }
        void callFunc() { if (m_Ptr != NULL) { m_Ptr(m_X, m_Y); }

   private:
      float x;
      float y;
      globalPositionCalculator m_Ptr;
};
```